# AWS Route53 | Alias record from other DNS providers

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

My client has a domain address on Godaddy and I would like to just connect A record to AWS Api Gateway without changing NS records because my client using other records such as MX and etc on Godaddy and would stay on it.

In Route53 we can create records by alias directly but in this case I'm not sure how could it be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I just did something similar with Amplify and I just imported the domain, changed the CNAME (following the Amplify docs - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html).

For API gateway, it might be a little different but I think you can go to Route 53 resolver and look for the inbound query link and then send it to your VPC of your Api Gateway endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Evan, I read all the doc but unfortunately it seems that there is no way to set DNS record out of Route53 because at this moment domain provider do not provide ANAME, but it gives me an idea to fix this problem. I gonna write it as answer below. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

Base on my recent searches on AWS documents and also Evan's document, there is no way without ANAME (Alias Name Record) that must provided by your DNS provider.

I'm not sure that my customer accept migration from existing DNS provider but I'm going to suggest below as our second solution:

**example.com couldn't set by ANAME but [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) could set CNAME then we can make a simple redirect from example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
I think Godaddy providing url redirect by default otherwise we must run an EC2 just for this redirection.**

I know it sucks but it seems that there is no any other way.

I will appreciated If someone knows better solution.